# Android focus from one LinearLayout to another LinearLayout on next pressing next button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, focus

What I required is to change the focus from `Edittext1` to `LinearLayout1` and the from `LinearLayout1` to `LinearLayout2` and the from `LinearLayout2` to `Edittext2`

I am not sure is this the valid to focus from one LinearLayout to another LinearLayout

Following is the xml file:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_welcome_txt"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editShowerName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:hint="Ghost Event Name"
                    android:inputType="text|textCapWords|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete" >
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp" >

                <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/month"
                    android:layout_width="120dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/day"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/year"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="125dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp" >

                <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/wv_hours"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/wv_minutes"
                    android:layout_width="40dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView
                    android:id="@+id/wv_am_pm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editDurationHours"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:hint="Hours"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

here I am able to get focus from Edittext to LinearLayout using `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for editText but this attritube is not supported by LinearLayout..

So how can move focus from one linear to another linear layout on pressing next button of device keyboard.Any kind of suggestion will be appreciate.Thanks in advance

Comment: android:focusable="true" in linearlayout

Comment: I have tried this but if I want to focus from one linearlayout to another linearlayout ...one thing is I am not getting next option on keyboard after I got focus from  edit text to linear layout .

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I needed both these lines for focus to actually work (especially for LinearLayouts).

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    />
```

Comment: Thanks man I will try and will let you know..reagrding android:clickable